# Dimensions of sum and intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X,Y$ be finite dimensional subspaces of vector space $V$.
If
$$
Z_1=X, Z_2=Y, Z_3=X+Y, Z_4=X \cap Y
$$
Can we conclude dim($Z_4$) $\leq$ dim($Z_1$)=dim($Z_2$) $\leq$ dim($Z_3$)? What must we know about the subspaces $X,Y$ for this to hold?

Comment: Nothing was assumed on $\dim(X)$ and $\dim(Y)$?

Comment: @Memming Nothing is assumed on dim($X$) and dim($Y$) but can we assume something so that this relationship is true?

Answer (score 0):

We just need to know that $X$ and $Y$ have equal dimension.

Comment: For $dim(Z_1)=dim(Z_2)$ we need that $dim(X)=dim(Y)$.